# Should I buy my Pi from Element 14 or the Raspberry Pi swag shop?

Tags: purchasing

Should I buy my PI from element 14 or the raspberry pi swag shop? it is less expensive from the swag shop. I want the best quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing as different "qualities" of the RPi's. Element 14 is the official distributor (and highly professional at that) so I highly doubt that there will be differences in quality. Outside the UK on the other hand it could be less desirable to order at rpi.org in terms of shipping (unfortunately I cannot find anything useful about shipping on their page prior to completion of an order - feel free to add).